# JNI : java - C // Using Global variables

Tags: java, android, c, java-native-interface

I would like to know whether JNI accepts the use of global variables declared in the .cpp (and of type created by me).

It would be for a speech recognition program. In fact, I would like to use C to declare all the settings of the decoder and Java to manage the recording thing on Android. I don't want to create a Decoder class on Java because it should be use both on Android and iOS (I would like to have 3 separate parts :

1) set up the decoder (only in C)

2) do the recording and manage the threads (only in Android-java)

3) decode the audio (in java but calling C functions that will use the settings of the decoder)

Example :

function.cpp :

```
struct decoder {
    char *model;
};
```

In the function_2.ccp file :

```
decoder *ps;

void set_decoder(char *modelToUse){
    ps->model = modelToUse;
    return;
}

void process(int *buf ) {
    process_raw(ps, buf); // modify buf accordingly to the parameters of ps
    return;
}

char *getHyp (){
    return ps->hyp;
}

void main(){
    ps = set_decoder(var1);

    jclass = android_class = (*env)->FindClass(env,"android/app/nameofactivity");  
    // find method_ID
    jmethodID android_mid = (*env)->GetStaticMethodID(env, android_class, "java_method",String_signature);

    // call method
    jString hyp_java = (*env)->CallIntMethod(env, android_class, android_mid, int samplerate);

EDIT (add these lines) :

const char *hyp_tmp = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, hyp_java, 0);
const char *hyp = hyp_tmp;
printf(hyp_java);

(*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, hyp_java, hyp_tmp);

//END of EDIT   

}
```

In the java file (the methods process and getHyp are declared as native methods ; the read method is a method from Android): 
file.java

```
String java_method(int samplerate){
    int buf[samplerate];
    recorder.read(buf);
    this.process(buf);
    return this.getHyp();
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

**EDIT : In brief, I wonder whether I can declare a global variable "ps" in C and then call a java function that will call other C functions that will use the value of the declared variable "ps".**

Comment: Where are your JNI functions? Your `getHyp` function returns a `char*`, which your Java code then appears to treat as a `String`. A `char*` is **not** a `String`. Also, there's no `main` in a shared object. There can be a `JNI_OnLoad` though.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer.
In fact, my question is on the the gestion of global variables declared in C and used through JNI. My code is a bit more complicated than that (but I've seen that my explanantion above is not very clear).
Yes, I know that String is not a char*. (i should use things like : 

const char *hyp_tmp = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, hyp_java, 0);
   const char *hyp = hyp_tmp;
   // use your string

   (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, hyp_java, hyp_tmp);

)

I just forgot to add these lines in my question. Sorry.

Comment: JNI can't stop you using global variables, but there are some things that aren't valid beyond the life of a JNI method, such as `JNIEnv` pointers and local references to objects, which are all described in the JNI Specification.

Comment: Ok thank you. 

So : do you think I can do something like that :

I set the decoder up in C, then call a java method with CallIntMethod that will use the parameters that I set up before in C. Will Java "remember" the parameters ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the answer to this question?